# Função recursiva com strings - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão

Não estou conseguindo resolver um exercício. O enunciado é o seguinte: Implemente a função incomodam(n) que devolve uma string contendo "incomodam " (a palavra seguida de um espaço) n vezes. Se n não for um inteiro estritamente positivo, a função deve devolver uma string vazia. Essa função deve ser implementada utilizando recursão.

Utilizando a função acima, implemente a função elefantes(n) que devolve uma string contendo a letra de "Um elefante incomoda muita gente..." de 1 até n elefantes. Se n não for maior que 1, a função deve devolver uma string vazia. Essa função também deve ser implementada utilizando recursão.

Por exemplo, o retorno da chamada **elefantes(4)** deve ser:

`Um elefante incomoda muita gente
2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muito mais
2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muita gente
3 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam muito mais
3 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam muita gente
4 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam incomodam muito mais`

Como posso implementar a segunda função de forma recursiva? Até agora só consegui como função iterativa.

```
def incomodam(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return ''
    else:
        return 'incomodam ' + incomodam(n - 1)

def elefantes(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return ''
    else:
        count = 1
        string = 'Um elefante incomoda muita gente ' 
        while count < n:
            count += 1
            if count < n:
                string += str(count) + ' elefantes ' + incomodam(count) + 'muito mais '
                string += str(count) + ' elefantes ' + incomodam(count) + 'muita gente '
            else:
                string += str(count) + ' elefantes ' + incomodam(count) + 'muito mais '

    return string
```

Comment: Tem como [edit] a pergunta e adicionar seus códigos?

Comment: Só conseguir implementar a primeira função. vou por.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiz assim:

```
def elefantes(n):
    if n <= 0: return ""
    if n == 1: return "Um elefante incomoda muita gente"
    return elefantes(n - 1) + str(n) + " elefantes " + incomodam(n) + ("muita gente" if n % 2 > 0 else "muito mais") +  + "\r\n"

def incomodam(n):
    if n <= 0: return ""
    if n == 1: return "incomodam "
    return "incomodam " + incomodam(n - 1)

>>> print(elefantes(0))

>>> print(elefantes(1))
Um elefante incomoda muita gente

>>> print(elefantes(2))
Um elefante incomoda muita gente
2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muito mais

>>> print(elefantes(3))
Um elefante incomoda muita gente
2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muito mais
3 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam muita gente

>>> print(elefantes(4))
Um elefante incomoda muita gente
2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muito mais
3 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam muita gente
4 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam incomodam muito mais
```

Comment: O que o enunciado pede na verdade é que todas aquelas linhas sejam um único retorno da função para chamada **elefantes(4)**, mas obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Não entendi. Não pode ser separado em duas funções, então?

Comment: podem, porém todas aquelas linhas de retorno que eu pus na pergunta tem que ser um unico retorno, no seu código quando eu faço a chamada **elefantes(4)** ela só retorna **4 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam incomodam muito mais**.

Comment: Verdade. Veja agora.

Comment: Ainda tem um erro no retorno, mas acho que consigo consertar, deveria, por exemplo retornar assim: elefantes(3)  **Um elefante incomoda muita gente
2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muito mais
2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muita gente
3 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam muito mais**, mas retorna **Um elefante incomoda muita gente
2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muito mais
3 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam muita gente**

Comment: Sim, creio ser agora uma questão de ajuste.

Comment: Em suma - a resposta é que a função "elefantes" também tem que ser recursiva.  E está bem correta.

Answer (score 1):

eu fiz assim:

```
    def incomodam(n):
        if n >= 1:
            return 'incomodam ' + incomodam(n-1)
        else:
            return ''

    quantidade = 0      
    muito= False        # pra saber em que parte esta da musica

    def elefantes(n):
        global quantidade
        global muito
        if quantidade == 0:
            quantidade,n = n,1
        if n <= quantidade:
            if n == 1:
                muito = True
                return 'Um elefante incomoda muita gente\n'+elefantes(n+1)
            else:
                if muito:
                    muito = False
                    return str(n) + ' elefantes ' + incomodam(n) + 'muito mais\n' + elefantes(n)
                else:
                    muito = True
                    if n+1>quantidade:
                        quantidade = 0
                        return ''
                    else:
                        return str(n) + ' elefantes ' + incomodam(n) + 'muita gente\n' + elefantes(n+1)
        else:
            return ''
```

Comment: valeu pela por ter avisado

Answer (score 0):

Eu também tive que fazer esse código para um curso. Eu percebi que o caso era especial não apenas para n=1, mas também para n=2. Para n=2, a função seria chamada "parcialmente". Por tanto, resolvi dessa forma:

```
def incomodam(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return ""
    elif n % 1 == 0:
        return "incomodam " + incomodam(n-1)
    else:
        return ""

def elefantes(n):
    if n == 1:
        return "Um elefante incomoda muita gente"
    elif n == 2:
        return elefantes(n-1) + f"\n{n} elefantes "+ incomodam(n) +"muito mais" 
    elif n > 2:
        frase1 = f"\n{n-1} elefantes incomodam muita gente"
        frase2 = f"\n{n} elefantes "+ incomodam(n) +"muito mais"
        return elefantes(n-1) + frase1 +frase2
    else:
        return ""
```

Percebe-se que quando n=2, apenas a frase 2 é chamada, já que a frase 1 tem que estar no singular...

Sugiro usar o pytest para checar os resultados.

```
import pytest
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input,expected", [
    (0, ""),
    (1, "Um elefante incomoda muita gente"),
    (2, "Um elefante incomoda muita gente\n2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muito mais"),
    (3,"Um elefante incomoda muita gente\n2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muito mais\n2 elefantes incomodam muita gente\n3 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam muito mais"),
    (4,"Um elefante incomoda muita gente\n2 elefantes incomodam incomodam muito mais\n2 elefantes incomodam muita gente\n3 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam muito mais\n3 elefantes incomodam muita gente\n4 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam incomodam muito mais"),
    (-1,""),
])
def test_eval(test_input, expected):
    assert elefantes(test_input) == expected
```