# Repetição de palavras

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo que canta a música do elefante, acredito que todos conheçam. Quem não conhece, funciona da seguinte forma:

> a) Para o primeiro elefante, escrever no singular.
>
> b) Para o segundo elefante em diante escrever elefantes.
>
> c) Sempre que a quantidade de elefantes for impar escrever: X
>   elefantes incomodam muita gente!, onde X é a quantidade de elefantes.
>
> d) Sempre que a quantidade de elefantes for par, repetir a palavra
>   incomodam pela metade da quantidade de elefantes existentes, por
>   exemplo, 6 elefantes incomodam, incomodam, incomodam muito mais!.

Já existe aqui no SOpt a seguinte pergunta que aborda o mesmo assunto: [Função recursiva com strings - Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/208135/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-recursiva-com-strings-python). Entretanto eu não desejo utilizar funções para resolver este problema, pois como estou aprendendo a linguagem ainda, entendo que preciso preencher algumas lacunas no meu conhecimento antes de começar a utilizar funções.

O código está aqui:

```
a = int(input("Digite a quantidade de elefantes: "))
for i in range(1,a):
    if i == 1:
        print("{} elefante incomoda muita gente.".format(i))
    if i % 2 == 0 and i > 1:
        print("{} elefantes incomodam muito mais.".format(i))
    if i % 2 != 0 and i > 1:
        print("{} elefantes incomodam muita gente.".format(i))
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Como vocês podem perceber, o código que escrevi não faz essa parte do problema:

> repetir a palavra incomodam pela metade da quantidade de elefantes existentes

A dúvida é a seguinte: Que função posso utilizar para fazer essa repetição?

Tentei concatenar, mas não deu certo. Tentei a função `join()`, mas confesso que não entendi muito bem a sintaxe quando li a documentação.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss eu ainda não sei utilizar funções, por isso desconsiderei a pergunta que você marcou como duplicata. Quero fazer sem utilizar funções.

Comment: Sem contar que a resposta da outra pergunta é apenas um bloco de código, não há explicação alguma ou informação nela.

Comment: Cadu, essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/264700/5878) mostra como fazer utilizando estruturas de repetições; a função ali é apenas uma organização a mais.

Comment: Como lá pede explicitamente para ser de forma recursiva, resolvi abrir a pergunta.

Comment: `" ".join(["incomodam"] * num)` faz o que você quer. Formulo uma resposta decente com melhores explicação a tarde (se alguém não o fizer antes)

Comment: @fernandosavio o Anderson já fez, mas eu agradeço se você fizer, pois será uma outra forma de aprender a fazer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um objeto do tipo *string*, no Python, permite ser multiplicado por um inteiro gerando uma nova *string* sendo a primeira repetida várias vezes. Veja:

```
>>> 'incomodam ' * 3
incomodam incomodam incomodam
```

Assim, quando o valor for par, basta adicionar essa *string* no texto:

```
if i % 2 == 0 and i > 1:
    print("{} elefantes {}muito mais.".format(i, 'incomodam ' * (i//2)))
```

Desta forma, seu código produzirá:

```
Digite a quantidade de elefantes: 7
1 elefante incomoda muita gente.
2 elefantes incomodam muito mais.
3 elefantes incomodam muita gente.
4 elefantes incomodam incomodam muito mais.
5 elefantes incomodam muita gente.
6 elefantes incomodam incomodam incomodam muito mais.
```

Perceba que, inclusive, utilizei `i // 2` e não apenas `i / 2`; isso porque a divisão `i/2` retornará um *float*, enquanto `i//2` retornará um inteiro. A *string* permite ser multiplicada por um inteiro, não por um *float*. O mesmo resultado seria obtido se multiplicasse por `int(i/2)`.

Também é importante observar os parenteses: `'incomodam ' * (i//2)`. Eles servirão para definir como prioridade a operação de divisão e não a de multiplicação. Por possuírem naturalmente a mesma prioridade, o interpretador iria analisar a expressão da esquerda para a direita, efetuando primeiro a multiplicação e depois a divisão. Neste caso, você teria `'incomodam incomodam incomodam ' // 2`, o que não faz sentido algum (inclusive daria erro dizendo *unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'*).

Lembre-se também que `range(1, n)` gerará o conjunto `[1, n-1]`, por isso quando informado 7 elefantes, a saída chega apenas em 6. Isso fará menos sentido ainda quando a entrada for 1, pois não haverá saídas no programa. Talvez seja interessante corrigir para `range(1, a+1)`.

Comment: Essa / a mais faz toda a diferença. Eu tinha feito o que você falou, só que somente com uma /, aí dava aquele erro de que não é possível multiplicar uma string por um float. Muito obrigado!